# Is the voltage 220-240 V at 50 Hz *everywhere* in Europe?

Tags: europe, power

I have seen references saying that the voltage in [Europe](http://www.enjoy-europe.com/hte/chap11/electric.htm) is 220-240V at 50Hz. Are there any exceptions to this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No exceptions. Wikipedia has a colourful map of [mains voltage systems used around the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country).

[image]

Comment: The sockets differ though...